# Disable Syntax Errors in CDT Project during runtime

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

In a C/C++ Project I can disable Syntax Errors by right click on the project, then `C/C++ General -> Code Analysis`.

It looks like this:
[image: Disable Syntax and Semantic Erors in Project Properties]

Is there a way to do this at runtime for my eclipse plugin? In my Eclipse Plugin I like to have the Syntax and Semantic Errors disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done using CodAn's public API. I don't have a fleshed out code example, but based on some quick poking around in the APIs used by the preference page in the screenshot, a rough outline of the steps would be:

- Use `org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.CodanRuntime.getInstance().getCheckersRegistry().getWorkspaceProfile()` to get the "problem profile" (settings for each type of CodAn problem) for the workspace.
- Use `IProbemProfile` APIs such as `findProblem(String id)` to find the checkers of interest. Each checkable entry on that preference page will be an `IProblem`.
- Cast the `IProblem` to `IProblemWorkingCopy` and use `IProblemWorkingCopy.setEnabled()` to modify the enablement.